# Unable to connect to Aurora MYSQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-aurora, aws-security-group

Hi I have created the Aurora database with MySQL Compatibility. Given public access as this is for the current dev/sample environment. Did not create any VPC, but it uses the default one, for which I have checked the subnets if it has route table to internet gateway and if it is allowing the security group and Network ACL to 0.0.0.0/0 and Mysql port. I dont have firewall blocking the port 3306. It is not serverless as well. I tried to ping and got request timeout from my laptop. Please help. Thanks.

Ping request gives me below error

```
Request timed out.
```

Connecting via mysql command gives me below error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'x.x.x.x' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: Updated the post with error. I have installed mysql 5.7 in my laptop and the AWS for my region supports 5.6. Is is something to do with this? But then, I have to be able to ping the endpoint atleast. isnt it?

Comment: Right does the user `admin` exist and have you checked he password? This is a credentials error :)

Comment: Yes it is. Found from the forum , it suggest to create new password rather than using the generated password and it works now

Comment: OK great, updated my answer to include this information in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

It was confirmed to be a credentials issue, the OP reset their password which resolved the issue.

**Original**

The error you have is a credentials error, this proves connection between your host and Aurora is possible  via the MySQL port.

The following should be checked to resolve the issue:

- Check the username, if this was created with the Aurora Cluster check the console to ensure that it is spelt correctly.
- Check the password you're entering is correct, if this is the user you created with the Aurora cluster then [reset the password](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/reset-master-user-password-rds/) from the console.

Regarding ping, the AWS knowledge center says

> Amazon RDS doesn't accept internet control message protocol (ICMP) traffic, including ping.

Below is more information about [resolving connectivity issues](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-cannot-connect/) from the knowledge center.